# Django foreign key issue

Tags: python, django

I have a requirement where I am creating user and want to define foreign key relation by creating other user and link both. Mean `user1` is created by `user2` and `user2` is stored in different model.

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Not sure about how to implement this. Help appreciated!

Comment: You want to have a model `MyUser` with relation to django's `User` model from `django.contrib.auth`?

Comment: Could you please add a bit more information about what you are trying to achieve and the codebase which already been used there?

Comment: I am creating a class inherited from model.Model and using foreign key from existing User. I can see data in form still form.is_valid() returns false.

Comment: If you're not too keen on an FK relation, you could just store the id of the creator user